# Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
function getTotalResultsInfo(gAuthor, gOther) {
// Generate correct http request
var url_to_get = "http://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_q=" + gOther + "&num=" + ret_results + "&as_sauthors=" + gAuthor;

$.getJSON(url_to_get, function (data) {
    totalCount(data);
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
});}
```

It does not seem working, but gives me

**"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_q=&num=100&as_sauthors=daniel. Origin "http://localhost:4448" is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**."

My friend told me that it is a cross-domain ajax problem. But I do not know how to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

You'd achieve that by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in the header of the web page on the server. That's fine if you own the server but isn't going to be an option for a Google page, you'll need to go about retrieving the data a different way rather than straight through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) header is necessary to load data from a different origin (a combination of protocol, hostname, and port number) using XMLHttpRequest.

If the site (scholar.google.com) were yours, you could change the server-side code to send that header. However, it is a third-party site, so you cannot do that. Short of an alternative access method such as a [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp) API, there is only one way to get around the limitation.

You would need to set up a [proxy script](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) on your Web server, which you could write in C#, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, or any other programming language. From the web browser's perspective, jQuery's connection would be to your server, not to Google. From Google's perspective, the connection would be from your server, not from your web browser.

If the Web server is publicly accessible, you would have to lock the proxy script to prevent abuse (e.g. a hacker using it to attack another web site). However, speaking of abuse, there is a more immediate issue. Google might consider your queries to be in violation of their terms of service, and they could block your access at any time. There are ways to avoid being caught, although they fall outside the scope of your question.